# Extension of a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow X$ to a function $g: E\rightarrow E$ such that $X$ is embedded in $E$, a Banach space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, weak-topology

We consider a compact metric space $X$ and a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow X$. I know it's possible to embed $X$ into a Banach or separable Hilbert space $E$ using the weak star topology. However I'm interested in whether it's possible to extend a continuous function such as $f$ to the whole space $E$ once you embed $X$ on $E$. I know something like this should be possible because of representations of dynamical systems on Banach spaces, however I haven't seen a direct proof of what I'm asking here, so any help or source would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google "Dugundji extension theorem".

Comment: When I talk about a hilbert space I don't mean the space $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} [0,1]$, I mean a hilbert space such as $l_2$.

Comment: Me neither: I know what a Hilbert space is and never confuse it with the Hilbert cube.

Comment: Could you be more explicit in how to use digundji extension theorem for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, all what you need is a [generalization of the Tietze Extension Theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_prolongement_de_Dugundji) due to Dugundji, see

*Dugundji, James*, [**An extension of Tietze’s theorem**](https://doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1951.1.353), Pac. J. Math. 1, 353-367 (1951). [ZBL0043.38105](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0043.38105).

or, for a textbook treatment, Chapter III, Theorem 7.1 in

*Borsuk, Karol*, Theory of retracts, Monografie Matematyczne. 44. Warszawa: PWN - Polish Scientific Publishers. 251 p. (1967). [ZBL0153.52905](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0153.52905).

or simply read the proof in the linked Wikipedia article if your French is sufficiently good.

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a closed subset of a metric space $X$, let $V$ be a locally convex topological vector space (e.g. any Banach space). Then for every continuous map $f: A\to V$ there exists a continuous extension $F: X\to V$. (Moreover, the image of $F$ can be taken to lie in the closed convex hull of $f(A)$ in $V$, but we will not need this.)

Now, if you have a compact metrizable space $K\subset V$ embedded in a Banach space $V$, and a continuous self-map $f: K\to K$, you simply take $X=V$, $A=K$. Then apply the above extension theorem. (I assume that you know how to prove that $K$ is closed in $V$.)